# auto_increment not setting value for primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I'm baffled, when I use the terminal (mysql) and insert into `username`,`account_password` columns, user_id AUTO_INCREMENTS just as it should.

my table:

```
        CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id int NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_type VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  creation_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(100) NOT  NULL,
  account_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

yet when I use this script:

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';# good for debugging, FATAL kills program so warnings are more identifiable
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); # good for debugging, sends info to browser
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256);

print header, start_html;
my $fName    = param('firstName');
my $lName    = param('lastName');
my $compName = param('compName');
my $email    = param('email');
my $pswrd    = param('password');
my $cnfPswrd = param('confPassword');
my $encpswrd = "";

#check passwords match, if not display error, and exit script
if ($pswrd eq $cnfPswrd) {
    $encpswrd = sha256($pswrd);
} else {
    print "Passwords did not match! refresh form!";
    exit;
}

#database credentials, to be changed accordingly
my $database = "intsystest";
my $host     = "localhost";
my $user     = "root";
my $pw       = "password";
my $dsn      = "dbi:mysql:$database:localhost:3306";

#connect to database
my $dbh      = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw,
                           { RaiseError => 1 }) or die "unable to connect:$DBI::errstr\n"; # <- this line good for debugging

#create, prepare, execute query, disconnect from DB
my $personsQuery = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?)";
my $compQuery    = "INSERT INTO company (company_name) VALUES (?)";
my $usersQuery   = "INSERT INTO users (username, account_password) VALUES (?,?)";

my $sth   = $dbh->prepare($personsQuery); 
$sth->execute($fName, $lName);
$sth      = $dbh->prepare($compQuery);
$sth->execute($compName);
$sth      = $dbh->prepare($usersQuery);
$sth->execute($email, $encpswrd);
$dbh -> disconnect;

# additional processing as needed ...

print end_html;
```

I get this error:

```
 DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/compSignUpDBCGI.pl line 44.
```

I'm assuming it's likely something wrong with the handler. What am I missing??

Comment: I presume there's no `user_id` field in the `persons` or `company` table?

Comment: there is a foreign key field in `persons`, but none in the `company` table.

Comment: So are you sure it's not that query causing the error? If it's a foreign key I'm guessing it doesn't have a default value.

Comment: im sorry, but there is a user_id field.
`user_id INT NOT NULL`

Comment: thank you I didn't consider that. Should I set it to auto_increment in `persons` also? I appreciate the help, this is my first internship so I am new to this stuff.

Comment: If that field is a foreign key pointing to `users`, you will need to do the insert into `users` first, then get the new `user_id` field from there (look into `last_insert_id`) and use that in the insert into the `persons` table. If it's not a foreign key, setting it to `auto_increment` should be fine.

Comment: I've been at this for the last ten hours, and am just about going cross eyed! `FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)` it is indeed a foreign key, I tried moving the handle for the `$usersQuery` to prepare and execute before the `$personsQuery` but to no avail.

Comment: You'll need to get the `last_insert_id` from the insert into `users` and then add that value to the insert into `persons` query.

Comment: Fell asleep as it was late where I am. Thank you! so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `persons` table has a foreign key to the `users` table then you need insert the `users` record first, then get the id of the new `users` record and add that to the SQL to insert the `persons` record.

Something like this:

```
my $usersQuery   = "INSERT INTO users (username, account_password) VALUES (?,?)";
$sth      = $dbh->prepare($usersQuery);
$sth->execute($email, $encpswrd);

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = ?');
$sth->execute($email);
my $user_id = $sth->fetch->[0];

my $personsQuery = "INSERT INTO persons (user_id ,first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$sth   = $dbh->prepare($personsQuery); 
$sth->execute($user_id, $fName, $lName);
```

This is an area where [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class.pod) will definitely make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I could see the problem but didn't know `perl` well enough to produce one.

Comment: You can also get the last insert ID and thus not need to depend on the username to find the inserted ID by running `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` or calling `$dbh->last_insert_id` after running the first `INSERT`.